# Transformar fecha con javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo la siguiente fecha

```
2019-10-30T18:13:18
```

Necesito transformarla en este caso a lo siguiente

30 Octubre 2019

Pero no se como hacerlo ._. estoy buscando como transformarla pero nada a ver si alguien me puede arrojar algo de luz...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes transformarla desde ese formato (creo que es ISO)
A un formato de fecha local en español.
Te dejo un ejemplo, solo debes quitarle el dia como nombre ;)

```js
const event = new Date("2019-10-30T18:13:18");

const options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };

console.log(event.toLocaleDateString('es', options));
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo único que tienes que hacer es emplear los diferentes métodos *getDate*, *getMonth* y *getFullYear* del objeto Date que tengas.

A partir de ahí el único problema es devolver el mes como te interesa. En este caso sólo tienes que hacer un array con los nombres de los meses y obtener el del mes en cuestión, que puestos de forma ordenada sale directo.

```js
var fecha = new Date();
var dia = fecha.getDate();
var mes = fecha.getMonth();
var year = fecha.getFullYear();

var meses = ['Enero','Febrero','Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'];

mes = meses[mes];

console.log(dia+' '+mes+' '+year);
```